# Scheduling a build using Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubectl

The doc https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/cron_jobs.html provides details of creating a cron job.

To start a scheduled task that executes a build every 10 mins I use the command:

```
oc run run-build 161/my-app --image=myimage --restart=OnFailure --schedule='*/10 * * * *'
```

Which returns:

```
cronjob.batch/run-build created
```

But the job fails to start:

The log of pod displays:

```
Error: unknown command "161/my-app" for "openshift-deploy"
Run 'openshift-deploy --help' for usage.
```

Have I configured the command ( `oc run run-build 161/my-app --image=myimage --restart=OnFailure --schedule='*/10 * * * *'` ) to start the cron job incorrectly ?

Comment: What is `161/my-app` ? It looks like your container runtime can't execute command `161/my-app`. Depending on the image you are using, you may be missing the proper shell or correct entrypoint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are trying to override the image `CMD`/`ARG` with the `161/my-app` command (which seems not to be valid).

You should use:

```
oc run run-build --image=myimage --schedule='*/10 * * * *' \
--restart=OnFailure \
--command -- <YOUR COMMAND HERE>
```

*Where `run-build` is the name of your created cronjob.*

If you want to use the default `CMD`/`ARG` built in the container image, just omit the `--command` flag and its value.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, It is not easy to find a full docs for the `oc run`, so let's discuss with the [source code](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/v3.9.0/pkg/oc/cli/cmd/wrappers.go#L477)

---

As the `cronjob.batch/run-build` has been created, the build is scheduled by kubernetes, so there may be no problem for the schedule part.

The prolem is now why the image run failed.

we can find it from the logs, `161/my-app` is recognized as an args for the command `openshift-deploy` which should be the CMD defined in `--image=myimage`

```
Error: unknown command "161/my-app" for "openshift-deploy"
Run 'openshift-deploy --help' for usage.
```

You have to expain the `161/my-app` and update the command based on it.

There is always a CMD defined in a Docker image, so we have to decide whether to use the default CMD:

If the default CMD would be used and want to modify the args: [Check this example](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/v3.9.0/pkg/oc/cli/cmd/wrappers.go#L463-L465)

```sh
oc run nginx --image=nginx -- <arg1> <arg2> ... <argN>
```

If a new CMD and args would be used: [Check this Example](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/v3.9.0/pkg/oc/cli/cmd/wrappers.go#L467-L468)

```sh
oc run nginx --image=nginx --command -- <cmd> <arg1> ... <argN>
```

---

I noticed two more infos in your questions, you can check here and update the question if necessary:

1. for the `openshift-deploy` part, you may reference [here](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/v3.9.0/pkg/cmd/infra/deployer/deployer.go#L67)
2. for the `openshift-build` part, you may reference [here](https://github.com/openshift/origin/blob/v3.9.0/pkg/cmd/infra/builder/builder.go)